# Removing all punctuation except - and _ from a java string using RegEx

Tags: java, regex, string, character-class

I am trying to replace all punctuation except the - and _ using a method I found here, but I can only get it to work on " using the exact code as posted which used a negative lookahead:

```
(?!")\\p{punct}

//Java example:

String string = ".\"'";
System.out.println(string.replaceAll("(?!\")\\p{Punct}", ""));
```

I tried:

```
name = name.replaceAll("(?!_-)\\p{Punct}", ""); // which just replaces all punctuation.

name = name.replaceAll("(?!\_-)\\p{Punct}", ""); // which gives an error.
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you happen to log in, please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a [character class subtraction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) (and add a `+` quantifier to match  chunks of 1 or more punctuation chars):

```
name = name.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}&&[^_-]]+", "");
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/souasM).

The `[\\p{Punct}&&[^_-]]+` means match any char from `\p{Punct}` class except `_` and `-`.

The construction you found can also be used, but you'd need to put the `-` and `_` into a character class, and use `.replaceAll("(?![_-])\\p{Punct}", "")`, or `.replaceAll("(?:(?![_-])\\p{Punct})+", "")`.

Comment: Nice. @Wiktor Any good tutorial to learn reg exp please? may with some advanced level tutorials explained as well?

Comment: Read [Lesson: Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) first. Then, I can suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew